# Is there any significance to Baile's Strand as the setting for Cúchulainn's duel with his son?

Tags: irish, ulster-cycle

Particularly geographical, historical, folkloric or linguistic connections.

I certainly can't find any such location on the map although there are a few coastal towns in Ulster that begin with "Bally", an alternate spelling. [Ballycastle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballycastle,_County_Antrim), for instance, seems to be associated with a legendary duel in which Congal, heir to the Kingdom of Ireland killed the King of Norway.

However, according to [*A Dictionary of Derivations*](https://books.google.com/books?id=W6NhAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA283&lpg=PA283&dq=strand%20of%20baile%20geography&source=bl&ots=hmByoubkhy&sig=Wleq7MaR5xQjKsbW75VKyYOXISo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwieorfhrNHPAhXL1R4KHeHNAVAQ6AEIMjAF#v=onepage&q&f=false), Sullivan, Robert (1860) p.283, the term is included in the names of at least 2000 Irish locations. From an etymological standpoint the word seems simply to mean a "place" or "settlement".

*Part of the reason I ask is that Yeats is a poet of the first order so I tend not to assume anything is random.  His plays are interesting, in part, because they occupy a place similar to the work of great Athenian dramatists, who commented on the great mythical cycles of their cultures, recorded centuries earlier by their forbearers.*

Answer (score 1):

From the entry on the Irish heroine *Ailinn* in Patricia Monaghan's "Encyclopedia of Celtic Mythology and Folklore":

> One of Ireland's greatest romances revolves around this princess of the southern Province of Leinster and her lover Baile Binnbhéarlach ("sweet-spoken Baile"), prince of Ulster in the northeast. As each traveled separately to a trysting place midway between their realms, a maleficent fairy told the prince—falsely—that his lover was dead, whereupon he died of grief at Baile’s Strand, a seashore near today’s Dundalk [...]

Similarly, from the same entry in Peter Berresford Ellis's "Dictionary of Celtic Mythology":

> The daughter of Laoghaire Mac Fergus Fairge (in another
> version, the daughter of Eoghan Mac Daithi). The granddaughter of the
> king of Leinster who falls in love with Baile, son of Buain and heir to the
> kingdom of Ulster. Ulster and Leinster were deadly enemies, and here we
> have a “Romeo and Juliet” tragedy. Aillinn and Baile arranged to meet on a
> shore near Dun Dealgan (Dundalk). Baile reached the appointed place first.
> A stranger approached and told him that Aillinn had died when she was
> prevented from coming to the meeting place. Baile dies from a broken
> heart. The stranger then appears to Aillinn and tells her of Baile’s own
> death. She dies of grief. We are not told who the malevolent stranger is
> apart from the fact that he is one of the gods. Baile is buried at Traigh
> mBaile (Baile’s Strand) and a yew tree grows from his grave; from Aillinn’s
> grave grows an apple tree. The poets of Ulster and Leinster cut branches
> from the trees and carved the story of the tragedy in Ogham on the wands
> made from the branches. According to the end of the story, 200 years later,
> when Art the Lonely was High King, the Ogham wands were gathered from
> Ulster and Leinster and taken to the Tech Screpta, or library, at Tara. As the
> wands were put into the library they sprang together and could not be
> separated.